# panda query with double quotation python

Tags: python, pandas

I want pandas query with text possibly have a double quote. This text variable is passed in as a parameter.

```
text = 'this is "dave"'

df.query(r'index != "text"')
```

Here, theres an error

```
SyntaxError: Python keyword not valid identifier in numexpr query
```

Therefore, I changed the text to escape double quote

```
text = text.replace('"','\"')
```

But the issue persists.

How do I fix this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `@` for pass variable to [`DataFrame.query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':list('abc'),
         'B':[4,5,6]

}, index=['this is "dave"','aa','bb'])

print (df)

                A  B
this is "dave"  a  4
aa              b  5
bb              c  6

text = 'this is "dave"'
print (df.query(r'index != @text'))
    A  B
aa  b  5
bb  c  6
```